# Mstest Pass/Fail report in sonarqube

Tags: c#, sonarqube, mstest, opencover, test-coverage

I have a solution with mstest unit testcases and using Opencover for testcoverage. 
TestCoverage results are coming fine in Sonarqube but it is not displaying the result from generated TestResult.trx file in Sonar. It only displays the unit test cases count but not testcases names, which one is pass and which one is fail.

I have followed the same steps mentioned in the link below:
https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=6389772#UnitTestExecutionResultsImport(C#,VB.NET)-MSTest

TRX file is also generated correctly but no data in sonar.

Please let me know if this possible or any alternative.

Below are the command I am using:

```
>MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe begin /k:rent /n:rent /v:1.0.0 /d:sonar.host.url=http://127.0.0.1:9000/ /d:sonar.exclusions=**/Files/**/* /d:sonar.cs.opencover.reportsPaths=E:\MSTest\rent\opencover.xml /d:sonar.cs.vstest.reportsPaths=E:\MSTest\rent\TestResults.trx

>MSBuild.exe /p:Configuration=debug /t:Publish /p:TargetProfile=Local E:\rent\rent.sln

>OpenCover.Console.exe -output:"E:\MSTest\rent\opencover.xml" -register:user -target:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest.exe" -targetargs:"/testcontainer:E:\rent\rent.Tests\bin\debug\rent.Tests.dll /resultsfile:E:\MSTest\rent\TestResults.trx" -excludebyattribute:*.ExcludeFromCodeCoverage*

>MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe end
```

Comment: Could you please share what versions of SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild and SonarC# are you using? (Note that SonarQube Scanner for CLI is not supported and if you are using it, you should switch to Scanner for MSBuild)

Comment: @Valeri-SonarSourceTeam I am using MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner.exe  and version SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild 2.2

Comment: What is the SonarC# version you are using (the SonarQube plugin)? Also please, edit your question and add the full begin step command you are executing, as well as the output from the runner.

Comment: @Valeri-SonarSourceTeam I have added the commands I am using.
And I am using SonarC# 6.2

Comment: The begin command looks fine, could you try adding `/d:sonar.verbose=true` at the end and after the analysis completes to send us the log?

Comment: @Valeri-SonarSourceTeam I have added the verbose=true and here is the some part of log:---

02:36:26.764 INFO: Parsing the Visual Studio Test Results file E:\MSTest\Rent\TestResults.trx
02:36:26.775 WARN: Metric 'test_success_density' is an internal metric computed by SonarQube. Provided value is ignored.